# Is Kinect orthographic or perspective mode?

Tags: kinect

I would like to know if the Kinect capture color, depth and IR images in `orthographic` or `perspective mode`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there is no clear mention of this particular information, based on my experience of using Kinect v1 and v2, I would say the following:

1. **Color and IR cameras**: Perspective 
   Both are normal RGB cameras (IR one has an IR filter) with a lens and have camera parameters, lens distortion etc. The objects in image get smaller as they go farther
2. **Depth**: Orthographic
   Based on how the depth is calculated [4], the depth image is a representation of a point cloud which removes the sense of perspective. [image]

[image: 2nd image Taken from [this SO question][2]]

Again, this might be wrong, but I believe it should be close enough. Apologies if it is wrong.

[4]: M. Andersen, T. Jensen, P. Lisouski, A. Mortensen, M. Hansen, T. Gregersen, and P. Ahrendt, “Kinect Depth Sensor Evaluation for Computer Vision Applications,” Technical Report Electronics and Computer Engineering, vol. 1, no. 6, 2015.

Comment: I am trying to save the raw depth values using Kinect not values (0-255) ... I look at one of your answers in another questions ... but I did not know how to use that code ! any ideas?

Comment: 1) Which code are you talking about?
2) Raw values can be saved easiiy. Since 8-bit depth images can only store values upto 0-255, actual depth data is lost when the image is saved. This means that since the maximum value that the Kinect can return is 8,000mm , to convert it into grayscale, the values are scaled to 256 parts. So each grayscale value represents 8000/255 = 31.25 mm of depth. So even though the actual depth value is lost when saving 8-bit depth images, the depth values can be re-calculated from the loaded image as follows:

imgDepth = 31.25*uint16(imread('Q2.png'));

Comment: Can we get the actual depth information without re-calculation step ? ... In addition, is it possible to save color, depth and IR from Kinect in the same time?