# Kinect depthmap distance to sensor position or sensor plane

Tags: kinect, depth

The Kinect creates a depthmap by measuring the 3D euclidean distance between a point and the sensor position for every pixel. This depthmap can then be reprojected into 3D camera space, for example as described in http://nicolas.burrus.name/index.php/Research/KinectCalibration

In particular, the z coordinate of the projected point is set to the measured depth of that pixel, which seems wrong to me, because it implies that the depth is measured as orthogonal distance to the sensor plane, not as 3D euclidean distance to the sensor position.

So which one is correct? Distance to sensor plane or distance to sensor position?

Comment: one would project to the screen plane and one would look like a fisheye.

Answer (score 0):

The measured depth is calculated as orthogonal distance, as described by [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFehu.png) and given by the figure below:

[image]

Another similar answer can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47517836/is-kinect-orthographic-or-perspective-mode/47548018#47548018)..

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFehu.png): M. Andersen, T. Jensen, P. Lisouski, A. Mortensen, M. Hansen, T. Gregersen, and P. Ahrendt, “Kinect Depth Sensor Evaluation for Computer Vision Applications,” Technical Report Electronics and Computer Engineering, vol. 1, no. 6, 2015.